# Why does numpy handle overflows inconsistently?

Tags: python, numpy, overflow

How come the following test works fine on Windows, but fails on Linux:

```
import numpy as np

print(f"Numpy Version: {np.__version__}")

# version A
versionA = np.eye(4)
versionA[:3, 3] = 2**32 + 1
versionA = versionA.astype(np.uint32)

# version B
versionB = np.eye(4, dtype=np.uint32)
versionB[:3, 3] = np.asarray(2**32 + 1)

# # version C
# # (raises OverflowError)
# versionC = np.eye(4, dtype=np.uint32)
# versionC[:3, 3] = 2**32 + 1

np.testing.assert_array_equal(versionA, versionB)
```

I tested this on Windows and Linux with numpy versions:
`1.23.4`, `1.21.5`, `1.24.0`. On Windows, the assignment overflows to `1` in both versions and the assertion compares as equal. On Linux, on the other hand, `versionB` overflows to `1`, but `versionA` results in assigning `0`. As a result, I get the following failure:

```
AssertionError:
Arrays are not equal

Mismatched elements: 3 / 16 (18.8%)
Max absolute difference: 4294967295
Max relative difference: 4.2949673e+09
 x: array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint32)
 y: array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint32)
```

Can someone explain why numpy behaves this way?

Comment: This is now tracked by https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22852

Answer (score 2):

**Numpy is based on C** and so it follows the C conventions. The thing is `np.eye(4)` is a `float64` number and `2**32 + 1` is larger than what `np.uint32` can handle. This means `versionA.astype(np.uint32)` will cause a **`float64 -> uint32` overflow**. This is an **undefined behaviour in C**. Numpy tries to detect errors like this without impacting performance, but AFAIK, this does not track all errors and it looks like an open problem to me. Indeed, from the point-of-view of Numpy developers, either we choose to have a complete deterministic platform-independent behaviour at the expense of possibly expensive checks, or we choose to accept undefined behaviours and report this as an expected behaviour in the documentation. As of now, the problem is not well documented but *most* errors are detected. Here is the related issue on the subject:

- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/21437
- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/21123

I strongly advise you to check the last version of Numpy (v1.24.0) which should contain the rework doing additional checks (ie. the first linked issue above). If this still not work with it, please fill an issue (with the related links above) so we can discuss about this (long standing) problem.

Comment: I expected something like this but was hoping that it is just me missing something obvious. I tried it with `1.24.0` and the behavior doesn't change, i.e., it continues to fail on Linux, but pass on Windows. I do, however, get a runtime warning on Linux about the invalid value of the cast during `versionA.astype(np.uint32)`.

Comment: Ok. The runtime warning is, I think, the best we can do without impacting performance so far in Numpy (the same applies for division by 0) and this is the expected behaviour we would like to have so far. Not having it on Windows is clearly not great (for portability) but AFAIK this behaviour is due to the platform that do not consider this as an overflow (it is correctly handled while it is still an undefined behaviour). I think it worth filling an issue on that, just for the record/discussion. I do not expect this to be fixed any time soon though.